# Symfony sfTCPDF plugin writeHTML error

Tags: symfony1, tcpdf

I'm using symfony 1.3, sfTCPDF plugin when i return a html content using curl execution tcpdf is throwing error

Here is my code

```
$url = "http://urlpath/builder/builder_dev.php/design/agreement?";
$arguments = "&pdfid=10";
$ch1 = curl_init();
$headerinfo = apache_request_headers();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arguments);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$headerinfo['User-Agent']);
$result = curl_exec($ch1);

$pdf->writeHTML("\n\n\n".$result, true, 0);
$pdf->Output('Agreement.pdf');
```

When i run the page it shows mnay warning messages first one is

```
Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: Unable to open '/var/www/html/projectPath/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf/cache/mska_01754b01ec8372f7001557e3be56ba40' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/projectPath/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php  on line 8109
```

based on the file it shows other warnings and 
Here is the error

```
TCPDF ERROR: Can't open image file: /var/www/html/projectPath/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf/cache/mska_01754b01ec8372f7001557e3be56ba40
Notice: Undefined property: sfTCPDF::$userData in /var/www/html/projectPath/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/sfTCPDF.class.php on line 112
```

I saw the path

```
/var/www/html/projectPath/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf/cache/
```

There is no cache folder. I gave 777 permission to the entire project folder. Eventhough it ends up with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is dealing with the same issue:
http://anthologize.org/trac/ticket/125

TCPDF wasn't adding the dir, so I think you just need to manually create it in older versions (this might be fixed by now).